# Firebase Test Labs User Usage

Tags: android, firebase, antivirus, firebase-test-lab, antimalware

I want to rent a lab from Firebase Test Labs for Android, but I wanted to ask if it is allowed to use this service for anti-virus and anti-malware application testing or is it against the user agreement?
To be more precise, I will be using the rented lab to test the effectiveness of an anti-malware tool that I implemented and need to test it.
Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because interpreting the (non-coding) terms of a service is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I do not get what the problem with my question is, I am only asking about the terms of user usage.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270278/can-i-ask-question-about-terms-of-cloud-services-or-generally-services-that-are

Comment: For such a question, I recommend to ask in the `#test-lab` Slack channel at https://firebase.community/